# How does one map many URLs to a single file using nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a static file, index.html. How would I configure nginx to serve it from every path on the domain?

```
    URL  | file
    -----------------
    /    | index.html
    /foo | index.html
    /bar | index.html
    /baz | index.html
```

Essentially, I want a wild card match.

(I realize this will be an unusual setup.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

`rewrite ^(.*)$ index.html`

Comment: Are you able to provide context? Where should this be inserted within the config file?

Comment: I got it to work in the end, using something similar to your suggestion: `rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;` (inside the `server { ... }` block).

Comment: rewrite * is a server block parameter. Those will always be expected to be within that block. My guess is, NGINX uses a internal expression to match the value of each instance of a single parameter - ```param | <capture string>``` ```(next line or /n /n```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem a while back and seem to remember doing something along the lines of:

```
server {
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   root /var/www/vhosts/example.com;
   location / {
      try_files index.html =404;
   }
}
```

If you don't mind returning an error code (e.g. you're down for maintenance) you could also do something like:

```
server {
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   root /var/www/vhosts/example.com;
   location / {
      error 503 index.html;
      return 503;
   }
}
```